# How did people decide which president to vote for 200 years ago?

Tags: political-history

A "long time ago" before there were TV's, radios, etc. what was the general method by which a presidential candidate in the United States would try to promote himself?  Was it by distributing pamphlets?  Publishing articles in local and national newspapers?  Sending representatives to spread the word?  How did it work, generally?

Comment: Very complex question; 200 years ago candidates did not campaign for office - their allies & supporters did. It would have been unseemly to actually seek office.  There is useful material is most Federalist History books. Madison's election to congress might be particularly useful.

Comment: Per the Constitution, they didn't have to. See [Electoral College on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_college). Share and enjoy.